# laravel 5.1 Model not found

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, laravel-5.1

I spend like 4 hours figuring this out but I'm unable to solve it.
I'm using laravel 5.1

I wish to view the owner of an organisation or the other way arround, check the organisations where a user is owner of.

I'm reciving the following error from my webserver:

```
FatalErrorException in Model.php line 893:
Class 'app\models\Organisation' not found
in Model.php line 893
at FatalErrorException->__construct() in HandleExceptions.php line 133
at HandleExceptions->fatalExceptionFromError() in HandleExceptions.php line 118
at HandleExceptions->handleShutdown() in HandleExceptions.php line 0
at Model->hasMany() in User.php line 19
at User->owner_of() in TestController.php line 24
at TestController->index() in Controller.php line 256
at call_user_func_array:{/home/shifts/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php:256}() in Controller.php line 256
at Controller->callAction() in ControllerDispatcher.php line 164
at ControllerDispatcher->call() in ControllerDispatcher.php line 112
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 139
```

My folder structure is the following:

```
- App/
-- Models/
--- Organisation.php
--- User.php
```

**User Model**

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model {

    protected $table = 'users';
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function owner_of()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Organisation', 'owner_id');
    }    
}
```

**Organisation Model**

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Organisation extends Model {

    protected $table = 'organisations';
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function owner()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User','owner_id','id');
    }
}
```

**Test Controller (code I'm executing)**

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Organisation;
use View;
use Debugbar;

class TestController extends Controller {

  /**
   * Display a listing of the resource.
   *
   * @return Response
   */
  public function index()
  {
    $site = url('test');
    echo "testpage <a href=\"$site\">Reload</a>";
    $u = User::find(1);
    var_dump($u);
    echo "<br /><br />";
    var_dump($u->owner_of());
    echo "<br /><br />";
    $o = Organisation::find(1);
    echo "<br /><br />";
    var_dump($o);
    echo "<br /><br />";

    var_dump($o->owner());
  }
}
```

**users scheme**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class UsersAccess extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users_roles', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->integer('ex_id');
            $table->string('obj',3);
            $table->integer('granted');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
}
```

**organisations scheme**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class CreateOrganisationsTable extends Migration {

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('organisations', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('owner_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }
}
```

Can someone point me out what I'm dooing wrong? I'm staring blind on this issue.
(this is the first time I'm trying to make a project in laravel 5.x)

Comment: Try running `composer dump-autoload` and see if that does the trick.

Comment: I just tried that, unfortunately it didn't solve it

Answer (score 3):

Even though they share the namespace, you still need to give the fully qualified paths to the relationship definitions:

```
public function owner_of()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Organisation', 'owner_id');
}
```

Comment: Hey Joel, Thanks that one I totally missed.

noneless I'm getting the following error.
`QueryException in Connection.php line 636:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.owner_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`owner_id` = 1) `

Also I changed my TestController a bit
Now I'm getting this error on this line: 
`Debugbar::info($o->owner()->get());`

Answer (score 0):

I can see in your table schema your table name is `users_roles` but in your model you used `protected $table = 'users';`

Either change your table name to `users` or change the table name in model `protected $table = 'user_roles';`